# Server Warning: The system load average

Tags: server

Why my web server will have warning message as below, how can I solve it ?
And my sever is attacked by the IP 107.148.145.215??

IP '107.148.145.215' currently has '55' connections

Connection info for '107.148.145.215':
tcp        0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55633   SYN_RECV
tcp        0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55632   SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55288   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55577   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55582   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55448   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55442   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55240   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55243   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55203   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55283   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55304   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55311   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55355   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55554   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55559   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55631   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55312   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55578   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55630   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55627   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55581   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55428   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55197   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55181   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55354   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55317   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55435   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55193   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55629   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55222   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55502   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55437   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55561   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55313   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55628   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55351   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55360   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55264   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55231   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55208   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55297   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55551   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55497   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55424   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55189   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55303   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55268   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55216   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55498   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55444   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55309   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55446   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55224   TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 103.11.102.59:443       107.148.145.215:55501   TIME_WAIT

/usr/sbin/ss output:
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23040279              * 23040280
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 23035809              * 23035808
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 22800153              * 22800152
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 14289                 * 14290
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 21547375              * 21545570
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /opt/dell/srvadmin/var/lib/openmanage/.ipc/dcsmilpipea 394954                * 396251
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23041217              * 23041218
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 23038005              * 23037090
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23037090              * 23038005
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 22801721              * 22801720
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 19618541              * 19618325
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /run/systemd/journal/stdout 862402                * 863381
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22880303              * 22880304
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22269367              * 22267585
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 21747419              * 21749101
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22801714              * 22799193
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22324284              * 22322846
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 22706177              * 22705226
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 19618445              * 19618322
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 19618431              * 19618313
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 15111                 * 17421
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 15091                 * 16361
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618677              * 19618722
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618508              * 19618511
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /run/systemd/journal/stdout 398927                * 397199
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 23036387              * 23036386
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22269368              * 22267588
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /run/systemd/journal/stdout 14294                 * 13312
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22799193              * 22801714
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22767519              * 22768263
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19621068              * 19618435
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 856096                * 855006
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 19618420              * 19619448
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 23040161              * 23040160
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23041140              * 23041141
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23038784              * 23038785
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21097884              * 21097354
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 19618447              * 19618324
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21545569              * 21547373
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 23039234              * 23039233
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19620359              * 19618448
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 19618498              * 19618495
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 22782793              * 22783164
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618316              * 19618425
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 19618417              * 19620348
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618313              * 19618431
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /run/systemd/journal/stdout 16378                 * 15176
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22705226              * 22706177
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22584365              * 22584366
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 20039551              * 20039552
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618525              * 19618528
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21749101              * 21747419
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 23036393              * 23036392
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22767521              * 22766579
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 22665108              * 22666431
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 19618533              * 19618530
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22801718              * 22801719
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 19618611              * 19618608
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618338              * 19618465
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618337              * 19618612
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21505976              * 21507332
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 22583610              * 22584368
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 19618602              * 19619454
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22783166              * 22782795
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22126820              * 22126819
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 22801715              * 22799194
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 19618689              * 19618496
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23036390              * 23036391
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22801320              * 22801705
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 19618534              * 19620358
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 22679448              * 22682621
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618672              * 19618721
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 22992984              * 22992983
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22803728              * 22802768
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22705227              * 22703603
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21469011              * 21470719
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 19618442              * 19618320
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19620354              * 19618423
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19620348              * 19618417
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618312              * 19618415
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 23037138              * 23036396
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 19618697              * 19618536
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23039233              * 23039234
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22801729              * 22801730
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 16516                 * 19625
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 28690                 * 25394
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 23041218              * 23041217
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 23041141              * 23041140
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22918058              * 22918059
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 22641155              * 22643075
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil-auth-penalty 19618682              * 19618680
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 396875                * 0
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23040076              * 23037777
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618352              * 19618479
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 22801727              * 22801726
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22666211              * 22666428
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 22322846              * 22324284
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 397397                * 395031
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 13153                 * 13152
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22801719              * 22801718
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22682620              * 22679447
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618321              * 19618519
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618314              * 19618416
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 32149                 * 31401
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 17421                 * 15111
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 22878984              * 22880295
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22802231              * 22803727
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23036392              * 23036393
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 22801716              * 22801325
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22666428              * 22666211
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 19618545              * 19618542
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 21550305              * 21550304
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21545573              * 21545574
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22801733              * 22801734
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618495              * 19618498
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22269369              * 22269370
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21550304              * 21550305
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 21545574              * 21545573
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 22782795              * 22783166
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22767520              * 22768264
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19621077              * 19618446
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23040160              * 23040161
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 22703603              * 22705227
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618323              * 19618529
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 19618423              * 19620354
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22918057              * 22918056
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 23037130              * 23036388
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21749098              * 21747418
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 22766579              * 22767521
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22584363              * 22584364
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21505974              * 21503445
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 20039553              * 20039554
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 19618529              * 19618323
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19620357              * 19618440
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22679447              * 22682620
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 21097354              * 21097884
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 19618722              * 19618677
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 19618679              * 19618676
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19619454              * 19618602
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 371030                * 369637
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 22878988              * 22880302
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22801704              * 22801319
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer 22267585              * 22269367
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618483              * 19618687
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618482              * 19618485
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22666431              * 22665108
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22666430              * 22666212
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 22124412              * 22126824
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 19618427              * 19618319
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19620349              * 19618433
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 23040325              * 23040324
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22184559              * 22183629
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 20039552              * 20039551
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 397199                * 398927
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 23039491              * 23039492
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 21747418              * 21749098
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22801325              * 22801716
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/login/login 19618698              * 19618543
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 22124411              * 22126823
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19619448              * 19618420
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 19618309              * 19618429
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /run/systemd/journal/stdout 14258                 * 14257
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/config 22990821              * 22992980
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 22880293              * 22878982
u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /var/run/dovecot/anvil 22583609              * 22584367
u_str  ESTAB      0      0         * 21505975              * 21507331
........

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this would be a better fit on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want that IP to stop "attacking" you, block it with iptables.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -s 107.148.145.215 -j DROP
```